# How to avoid conflict between JQ-UI Sortable and Droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a list of folders and items that could be imbricated - an UI that looks like those bookmark folders and links from some previous version of MozFF or other browsers that provides this kind of bookmark establishment.
I've started with some simple items here - http://jsfiddle.net/strategycon/GbVvW/4/.
The problem is that despite the fact that I provided the "tolerance" value for both draggable and sortable in order to create the posibility of triggering either drop or sort (tolerance: 'pointer' for droppable, so you can reach this easily and the other one when you insist more - tolerance: 'intersect' for sortable), droppable is triggered everytime, except when I drag the mouse at about 100px bottom or top from the placeholder and release the dragged item.
To be more crear:
**Scenario 1:** Drag "Item 2" and drop on "Item 1" - This is how I want droppable to work. Item 2 is part of Item 1 subItems. (The problem is that even if you get over Item 1 while dragging and you trigger the placeholder for sortable it will also be dropped as if you weren't)
**Scenario 2:** Drag "Item 2" against "Item 1" until you trigger the placeholder, then get de item 100px bottom then release - The sortable will work.
The question is: How cand I avoid triggering droppable ? Thank's!